# connected and compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is either a singleton or has uncountable boundary

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, reference-request

Let's say that $A\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is connected and compact but not a singleton.  I want to conclude that $\partial A$ is uncountable.  Can anyone help me find a reference to cite?

I can see how to prove this in a routine way, by picking distinct elements $a$ and $b$ in $A$, which we may assume without loss of generality have distinct real parts, and then finding an element in $\partial A$ with any real part strictly between the real parts of $a$ and $b$.  However, I would much rather just give a reference, since the argument is uninteresting.

Comment: @Ian which has uncountable boundary in C.

Comment: @Ian boundary is not an intrinsic property.

Comment: @Ian any neighborhood of a point on the interval contains points in the interval and not in the interval, hence any point on the interval is on the boundary.

Comment: @Ian Or try looking at it this way.  Recall that the boundary of a subset can be characterized as the set of points in the closure but not the interior.  Clearly, a subset of the real line has empty interior in $\mathbb{C}$.  That means every point would be in the boundary.

Comment: Never mind, I see what happened. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

The boundary of such a set is a perfect set (closed with no isolated points).  Such set in $\Bbb R^k$ is uncountable.  See Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis Theorem 2.43.